# Where would I ask for compatibility of different technologies?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm planing to build a webapp and want to use different technologies / frameworks I know or have at least heard that they would fit my needs. Since there are so many different types of frameworks now, I'm not sure wheter I could or should combine them. 
Jumping right into my example: I want to build a 3 tier web application where I'd like to mix multiple frameworks (Spring MVC, AngularJS, Hibernate) since I know what each framework does to some extend, I don't need to ask on [softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Next I'd use a JBoss to deploy and test on it locally. I'd probably need help from [superuser](https://superuser.com/). Jumping into production I'd need help from [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).
*But where would a place be to ask if I can combine:*

- MySQL as 1st tier (db)
- Hibernate & Spring MVC as 2nd tier (business logic)
- AngularJS as 3rd tier (presentation)

*and everything together on a JBoss?* Since it has a bit of everything but needs to be in context to solve my problem it's difficult to split it up. As for example I already know that I could combine AngularJS and Spring MVC using RESTful services from SO.

Comment: I think question should be scaled down to individual unit, so it can be asked on its relevant site...Combining the question will led user to skip answering,because they may know first part not second or so

Comment: [How can Stack Overflow help developers evaluate technologies?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/305678/839601)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That question is really too broad, specially for Stack Overflow.

There are so many use-cases, quirks, configuration options that you can write a book about it. The enormity of the topic doesn't fit well in the Q and A format used in the Stack Exchange Network of sites.

You might try a chatroom but I doubt they will be able to give a bite-size answer either.

One possible way around this is to create a small Proof of Concept for your technology stack and if you run into a specific issue, for example serialization issues between layers, you can ask about that specific issue. As a by-product you might learn from the answers that you have chosen a sub-optimal set of technologies. There is not enough jQuery for sure.

Outside of the SE network you might try Quora or Reddit as they are more geared to broad and opinion based topics.